# Non-sequential input choice filtering in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to generalize the [Hierarchical select boxes](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html#hierarchical-select) approach described in the Mastering Shiny book to enable non-sequential filtering. Currently, the drill-down approach only works if the user selects categories in a specific order, for example, Terriority -> Customer -> Order number. However, I would like the drill-down to work regardless of the initial input the user provides. Additionally, my application involves approximately 10 inputs, so I want the code to be scalable.

I have been following the example in the Mastering Shiny book, but I'm having difficulty adapting the code to allow for non-sequential filtering. Specifically, when I try to modify the code to accommodate non-sequential filtering, the select boxes become unresponsive.

Any suggestions for how to modify the code to allow for non-sequential filtering would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might find {shinyTree} ( https://github.com/shinyTree/shinyTree ) helpful. It offers you a collapsible/expandable hierarchial checkbox tree plus an input box to deep-search the tree nodes.

Comment: @ismirsehregal this is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you! Could you post an answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to apply the [selectizeGroup-module](https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/reference/selectizeGroup-module.html) from library([shinyWidgets](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets)) to the given example data.

This module creates a

> Group of mutually dependent `selectizeInput` for filtering
> data.frame's columns (like in Excel).

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

# csv source: https://github.com/hadley/mastering-shiny/blob/main/sales-dashboard/sales_data_sample.csv
# sales <- read.csv("sales_data_sample.csv")
# dput(head(na.omit(sales[, c("TERRITORY", "CUSTOMERNAME", "ORDERNUMBER")]), 100))

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 10, offset = 1, tags$h3("Filter data with selectize group")),
    column(width = 6, offset = 1, 
           selectizeGroupUI(
             id = "my-filters",
             params = list(
               TERRITORY = list(inputId = "TERRITORY", title = "TERRITORY:"),
               CUSTOMERNAME = list(inputId = "CUSTOMERNAME", title = "CUSTOMERNAME:"),
               ORDERNUMBER = list(inputId = "ORDERNUMBER", title = "ORDERNUMBER:")
             ),
             inline = TRUE
           )),
    column(
      width = 10, offset = 1,DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filtered_table <- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "my-filters",
    data = sales,
    vars = names(sales),
    inline = TRUE
  )
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(filtered_table(), rownames = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

**Example data:**

```
sales <- structure(list(TERRITORY = c("EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", 
"EMEA", "APAC", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "APAC", "EMEA", 
"EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "Japan", "APAC", "EMEA", 
"Japan", "APAC", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "APAC", "APAC", "EMEA", 
"APAC", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "Japan", "APAC", "EMEA", "EMEA", 
"Japan", "APAC", "APAC", "EMEA", "EMEA", "APAC", "EMEA", "EMEA", 
"EMEA", "Japan", "APAC", "EMEA", "EMEA", "Japan", "APAC", "EMEA", 
"EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", 
"EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", 
"EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "Japan", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "APAC", 
"APAC", "APAC", "EMEA", "EMEA", "APAC", "APAC", "APAC", "EMEA", 
"Japan", "EMEA", "APAC", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", 
"EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA"
), CUSTOMERNAME = c("Reims Collectables", "Lyon Souveniers", 
"Daedalus Designs Imports", "Herkku Gifts", "Auto Canal Petit", 
"Australian Collectors, Co.", "La Rochelle Gifts", "Toys of Finland, Co.", 
"Baane Mini Imports", "Salzburg Collectables", "Souveniers And Things Co.", 
"La Rochelle Gifts", "UK Collectables, Ltd.", "Euro Shopping Channel", 
"Baane Mini Imports", "Volvo Model Replicas, Co", "Corrida Auto Replicas, Ltd", 
"Dragon Souveniers, Ltd.", "Australian Gift Network, Co", "Saveley & Henriot, Co.", 
"Tokyo Collectables, Ltd", "Souveniers And Things Co.", "Amica Models & Co.", 
"Scandinavian Gift Ideas", "Auto Assoc. & Cie.", "Australian Collectors, Co.", 
"Anna's Decorations, Ltd", "Euro Shopping Channel", "Australian Collectors, Co.", 
"Lyon Souveniers", "Daedalus Designs Imports", "Herkku Gifts", 
"Osaka Souveniers Co.", "Australian Collectors, Co.", "La Rochelle Gifts", 
"Atelier graphique", "Tokyo Collectables, Ltd", "Souveniers And Things Co.", 
"Australian Gift Network, Co", "Auto Canal Petit", "Euro Shopping Channel", 
"Australian Collectors, Co.", "Lyon Souveniers", "Daedalus Designs Imports", 
"Herkku Gifts", "Osaka Souveniers Co.", "Australian Collectors, Co.", 
"La Rochelle Gifts", "Toys of Finland, Co.", "Tokyo Collectables, Ltd", 
"Australian Gift Network, Co", "UK Collectables, Ltd.", "Euro Shopping Channel", 
"Danish Wholesale Imports", "Salzburg Collectables", "Stylish Desk Decors, Co.", 
"Toys of Finland, Co.", "Scandinavian Gift Ideas", "Alpha Cognac", 
"Double Decker Gift Stores, Ltd", "Enaco Distributors", "Petit Auto", 
"giftsbymail.co.uk", "Baane Mini Imports", "Euro Shopping Channel", 
"Reims Collectables", "Oulu Toy Supplies, Inc.", "Lyon Souveniers", 
"Baane Mini Imports", "La Corne D'abondance, Co.", "Corrida Auto Replicas, Ltd", 
"Dragon Souveniers, Ltd.", "Mini Auto Werke", "Stylish Desk Decors, Co.", 
"Saveley & Henriot, Co.", "Handji Gifts& Co", "Handji Gifts& Co", 
"Souveniers And Things Co.", "Scandinavian Gift Ideas", "Volvo Model Replicas, Co", 
"Australian Collectors, Co.", "Anna's Decorations, Ltd", "Anna's Decorations, Ltd", 
"La Rochelle Gifts", "Cruz & Sons Co.", "Marseille Mini Autos", 
"Anna's Decorations, Ltd", "Herkku Gifts", "Toms Spezialitten, Ltd", 
"Euro Shopping Channel", "Auto Canal Petit", "Vida Sport, Ltd", 
"Danish Wholesale Imports", "UK Collectables, Ltd.", "L'ordine Souveniers", 
"Vida Sport, Ltd", "Blauer See Auto, Co.", "Toms Spezialitten, Ltd", 
"Volvo Model Replicas, Co", "Salzburg Collectables"), ORDERNUMBER = c(10121L, 
10134L, 10180L, 10188L, 10211L, 10223L, 10275L, 10299L, 10309L, 
10341L, 10361L, 10375L, 10403L, 10417L, 10103L, 10112L, 10126L, 
10150L, 10174L, 10194L, 10258L, 10270L, 10280L, 10291L, 10304L, 
10347L, 10391L, 10424L, 10120L, 10134L, 10180L, 10188L, 10210L, 
10223L, 10275L, 10298L, 10339L, 10361L, 10374L, 10402L, 10417L, 
10120L, 10134L, 10180L, 10188L, 10210L, 10223L, 10275L, 10299L, 
10339L, 10374L, 10403L, 10417L, 10105L, 10119L, 10129L, 10155L, 
10167L, 10178L, 10186L, 10197L, 10273L, 10316L, 10325L, 10350L, 
10359L, 10373L, 10395L, 10103L, 10114L, 10126L, 10150L, 10164L, 
10175L, 10194L, 10217L, 10259L, 10270L, 10291L, 10334L, 10347L, 
10370L, 10391L, 10425L, 10108L, 10122L, 10169L, 10181L, 10191L, 
10203L, 10211L, 10225L, 10238L, 10253L, 10266L, 10287L, 10300L, 
10310L, 10320L, 10341L)), na.action = structure(c(`1` = 1L, `4` = 4L, 
`5` = 5L, `6` = 6L, `9` = 9L, `12` = 12L, `13` = 13L, `14` = 14L, 
`16` = 16L, `19` = 19L, `20` = 20L, `24` = 24L, `30` = 30L, `32` = 32L, 
`34` = 34L, `36` = 36L, `37` = 37L, `38` = 38L, `39` = 39L, `45` = 45L, 
`46` = 46L, `47` = 47L, `49` = 49L, `50` = 50L, `51` = 51L, `53` = 53L, 
`55` = 55L, `58` = 58L, `59` = 59L, `60` = 60L, `63` = 63L, `66` = 66L, 
`67` = 67L, `68` = 68L, `70` = 70L, `72` = 72L, `73` = 73L, `74` = 74L, 
`78` = 78L, `81` = 81L, `84` = 84L, `85` = 85L, `86` = 86L, `89` = 89L, 
`92` = 92L, `93` = 93L, `94` = 94L, `96` = 96L, `98` = 98L, `99` = 99L, 
`100` = 100L, `102` = 102L, `104` = 104L, `110` = 110L, `116` = 116L, 
`117` = 117L, `118` = 118L, `119` = 119L, `121` = 121L, `122` = 122L, 
`123` = 123L, `126` = 126L, `130` = 130L, `132` = 132L, `133` = 133L, 
`137` = 137L, `141` = 141L, `143` = 143L, `145` = 145L, `146` = 146L, 
`149` = 149L, `151` = 151L, `152` = 152L, `153` = 153L, `156` = 156L, 
`158` = 158L, `160` = 160L, `164` = 164L, `165` = 165L, `166` = 166L, 
`176` = 176L, `181` = 181L, `189` = 189L, `190` = 190L, `194` = 194L, 
`195` = 195L, `200` = 200L, `201` = 201L, `209` = 209L, `210` = 210L, 
`212` = 212L, `214` = 214L, `216` = 216L, `220` = 220L, `222` = 222L, 
`224` = 224L, `225` = 225L, `228` = 228L, `231` = 231L, `232` = 232L, 
`233` = 233L, `235` = 235L, `237` = 237L, `239` = 239L, `241` = 241L, 
`244` = 244L, `245` = 245L, `248` = 248L, `249` = 249L, `252` = 252L, 
`253` = 253L, `254` = 254L, `255` = 255L, `256` = 256L, `259` = 259L, 
`260` = 260L, `262` = 262L, `264` = 264L, `269` = 269L, `270` = 270L, 
`274` = 274L, `275` = 275L, `280` = 280L, `281` = 281L, `285` = 285L, 
`290` = 290L, `291` = 291L, `294` = 294L, `295` = 295L, `296` = 296L, 
`306` = 306L, `311` = 311L, `314` = 314L, `319` = 319L, `320` = 320L, 
`324` = 324L, `325` = 325L, `330` = 330L, `331` = 331L, `337` = 337L, 
`340` = 340L, `341` = 341L, `342` = 342L, `345` = 345L, `346` = 346L, 
`347` = 347L, `357` = 357L, `362` = 362L, `369` = 369L, `370` = 370L, 
`376` = 376L, `377` = 377L, `378` = 378L, `379` = 379L, `382` = 382L, 
`383` = 383L, `384` = 384L, `385` = 385L, `387` = 387L, `389` = 389L, 
`391` = 391L, `392` = 392L, `397` = 397L, `398` = 398L, `399` = 399L, 
`402` = 402L, `413` = 413L, `414` = 414L, `422` = 422L, `424` = 424L, 
`428` = 428L, `430` = 430L, `431` = 431L, `432` = 432L, `433` = 433L, 
`439` = 439L, `440` = 440L, `441` = 441L, `443` = 443L, `445` = 445L, 
`447` = 447L, `449` = 449L, `454` = 454L, `456` = 456L, `457` = 457L, 
`463` = 463L, `467` = 467L, `468` = 468L, `471` = 471L, `473` = 473L, 
`476` = 476L, `477` = 477L, `480` = 480L, `481` = 481L, `483` = 483L, 
`486` = 486L, `493` = 493L, `494` = 494L, `496` = 496L, `498` = 498L, 
`501` = 501L, `502` = 502L, `503` = 503L, `506` = 506L, `507` = 507L, 
`509` = 509L, `512` = 512L, `519` = 519L, `520` = 520L, `524` = 524L, 
`525` = 525L, `527` = 527L, `533` = 533L, `535` = 535L, `536` = 536L, 
`538` = 538L, `542` = 542L, `546` = 546L, `547` = 547L, `549` = 549L, 
`551` = 551L, `555` = 555L, `556` = 556L, `563` = 563L, `564` = 564L, 
`566` = 566L, `569` = 569L, `577` = 577L, `579` = 579L, `581` = 581L, 
`582` = 582L, `583` = 583L, `585` = 585L, `587` = 587L, `594` = 594L, 
`595` = 595L, `597` = 597L, `599` = 599L, `603` = 603L, `604` = 604L, 
`605` = 605L, `608` = 608L, `615` = 615L, `619` = 619L, `620` = 620L, 
`627` = 627L, `632` = 632L, `634` = 634L, `635` = 635L, `637` = 637L, 
`641` = 641L, `645` = 645L, `646` = 646L, `651` = 651L, `655` = 655L, 
`656` = 656L, `662` = 662L, `663` = 663L, `664` = 664L, `668` = 668L, 
`669` = 669L, `670` = 670L, `671` = 671L, `673` = 673L, `675` = 675L, 
`677` = 677L, `678` = 678L, `681` = 681L, `683` = 683L, `684` = 684L, 
`685` = 685L, `687` = 687L, `689` = 689L, `696` = 696L, `699` = 699L, 
`701` = 701L, `705` = 705L, `711` = 711L, `712` = 712L, `713` = 713L, 
`716` = 716L, `717` = 717L, `718` = 718L, `719` = 719L, `720` = 720L, 
`721` = 721L, `723` = 723L, `731` = 731L, `732` = 732L, `733` = 733L, 
`735` = 735L, `737` = 737L, `740` = 740L, `744` = 744L, `745` = 745L, 
`749` = 749L, `751` = 751L, `757` = 757L, `763` = 763L, `765` = 765L, 
`768` = 768L, `769` = 769L, `771` = 771L, `772` = 772L, `773` = 773L, 
`776` = 776L, `778` = 778L, `785` = 785L, `786` = 786L, `789` = 789L, 
`790` = 790L, `791` = 791L, `795` = 795L, `796` = 796L, `799` = 799L, 
`803` = 803L, `805` = 805L, `808` = 808L, `809` = 809L, `810` = 810L, 
`813` = 813L, `816` = 816L, `817` = 817L, `818` = 818L, `820` = 820L, 
`822` = 822L, `823` = 823L, `824` = 824L, `826` = 826L, `835` = 835L, 
`836` = 836L, `838` = 838L, `848` = 848L, `849` = 849L, `853` = 853L, 
`855` = 855L, `856` = 856L, `857` = 857L, `862` = 862L, `864` = 864L, 
`865` = 865L, `867` = 867L, `871` = 871L, `875` = 875L, `876` = 876L, 
`880` = 880L, `887` = 887L, `889` = 889L, `891` = 891L, `892` = 892L, 
`893` = 893L, `895` = 895L, `900` = 900L, `901` = 901L, `902` = 902L, 
`904` = 904L, `905` = 905L, `906` = 906L, `910` = 910L, `914` = 914L, 
`916` = 916L, `918` = 918L, `919` = 919L, `920` = 920L, `922` = 922L, 
`927` = 927L, `928` = 928L, `931` = 931L, `932` = 932L, `933` = 933L, 
`938` = 938L, `939` = 939L, `945` = 945L, `946` = 946L, `947` = 947L, 
`950` = 950L, `952` = 952L, `960` = 960L, `961` = 961L, `963` = 963L, 
`967` = 967L, `969` = 969L, `971` = 971L, `972` = 972L, `973` = 973L, 
`975` = 975L, `980` = 980L, `981` = 981L, `984` = 984L, `985` = 985L, 
`986` = 986L, `992` = 992L, `994` = 994L, `996` = 996L, `997` = 997L, 
`1001` = 1001L, `1003` = 1003L, `1012` = 1012L, `1013` = 1013L, 
`1015` = 1015L, `1018` = 1018L, `1023` = 1023L, `1025` = 1025L, 
`1029` = 1029L, `1030` = 1030L, `1032` = 1032L, `1035` = 1035L, 
`1041` = 1041L, `1042` = 1042L, `1043` = 1043L, `1045` = 1045L, 
`1047` = 1047L, `1049` = 1049L, `1050` = 1050L, `1051` = 1051L, 
`1052` = 1052L, `1055` = 1055L, `1069` = 1069L, `1073` = 1073L, 
`1074` = 1074L, `1078` = 1078L, `1080` = 1080L, `1089` = 1089L, 
`1090` = 1090L, `1093` = 1093L, `1094` = 1094L, `1095` = 1095L, 
`1105` = 1105L, `1109` = 1109L, `1110` = 1110L, `1114` = 1114L, 
`1116` = 1116L, `1119` = 1119L, `1120` = 1120L, `1122` = 1122L, 
`1124` = 1124L, `1125` = 1125L, `1128` = 1128L, `1130` = 1130L, 
`1132` = 1132L, `1134` = 1134L, `1136` = 1136L, `1137` = 1137L, 
`1138` = 1138L, `1143` = 1143L, `1144` = 1144L, `1145` = 1145L, 
`1155` = 1155L, `1165` = 1165L, `1166` = 1166L, `1171` = 1171L, 
`1173` = 1173L, `1174` = 1174L, `1176` = 1176L, `1180` = 1180L, 
`1184` = 1184L, `1185` = 1185L, `1187` = 1187L, `1193` = 1193L, 
`1194` = 1194L, `1195` = 1195L, `1201` = 1201L, `1203` = 1203L, 
`1204` = 1204L, `1208` = 1208L, `1214` = 1214L, `1218` = 1218L, 
`1219` = 1219L, `1225` = 1225L, `1226` = 1226L, `1227` = 1227L, 
`1230` = 1230L, `1232` = 1232L, `1240` = 1240L, `1244` = 1244L, 
`1245` = 1245L, `1249` = 1249L, `1250` = 1250L, `1251` = 1251L, 
`1255` = 1255L, `1256` = 1256L, `1257` = 1257L, `1260` = 1260L, 
`1261` = 1261L, `1262` = 1262L, `1267` = 1267L, `1268` = 1268L, 
`1270` = 1270L, `1272` = 1272L, `1274` = 1274L, `1276` = 1276L, 
`1286` = 1286L, `1288` = 1288L, `1293` = 1293L, `1295` = 1295L, 
`1297` = 1297L, `1302` = 1302L, `1303` = 1303L, `1305` = 1305L, 
`1310` = 1310L, `1314` = 1314L, `1315` = 1315L, `1319` = 1319L, 
`1323` = 1323L, `1325` = 1325L, `1327` = 1327L, `1328` = 1328L, 
`1331` = 1331L, `1333` = 1333L, `1334` = 1334L, `1338` = 1338L, 
`1340` = 1340L, `1341` = 1341L, `1344` = 1344L, `1346` = 1346L, 
`1350` = 1350L, `1352` = 1352L, `1353` = 1353L, `1354` = 1354L, 
`1355` = 1355L, `1358` = 1358L, `1361` = 1361L, `1362` = 1362L, 
`1363` = 1363L, `1367` = 1367L, `1368` = 1368L, `1372` = 1372L, 
`1373` = 1373L, `1374` = 1374L, `1382` = 1382L, `1383` = 1383L, 
`1387` = 1387L, `1393` = 1393L, `1395` = 1395L, `1399` = 1399L, 
`1401` = 1401L, `1405` = 1405L, `1412` = 1412L, `1414` = 1414L, 
`1417` = 1417L, `1420` = 1420L, `1421` = 1421L, `1422` = 1422L, 
`1423` = 1423L, `1425` = 1425L, `1427` = 1427L, `1432` = 1432L, 
`1435` = 1435L, `1437` = 1437L, `1440` = 1440L, `1441` = 1441L, 
`1447` = 1447L, `1448` = 1448L, `1453` = 1453L, `1454` = 1454L, 
`1455` = 1455L, `1456` = 1456L, `1458` = 1458L, `1460` = 1460L, 
`1462` = 1462L, `1467` = 1467L, `1470` = 1470L, `1471` = 1471L, 
`1472` = 1472L, `1475` = 1475L, `1478` = 1478L, `1479` = 1479L, 
`1480` = 1480L, `1482` = 1482L, `1485` = 1485L, `1486` = 1486L, 
`1488` = 1488L, `1498` = 1498L, `1500` = 1500L, `1501` = 1501L, 
`1503` = 1503L, `1506` = 1506L, `1510` = 1510L, `1513` = 1513L, 
`1515` = 1515L, `1520` = 1520L, `1521` = 1521L, `1524` = 1524L, 
`1525` = 1525L, `1530` = 1530L, `1534` = 1534L, `1538` = 1538L, 
`1542` = 1542L, `1543` = 1543L, `1544` = 1544L, `1546` = 1546L, 
`1551` = 1551L, `1555` = 1555L, `1556` = 1556L, `1560` = 1560L, 
`1565` = 1565L, `1568` = 1568L, `1570` = 1570L, `1573` = 1573L, 
`1576` = 1576L, `1577` = 1577L, `1578` = 1578L, `1580` = 1580L, 
`1582` = 1582L, `1583` = 1583L, `1584` = 1584L, `1594` = 1594L, 
`1598` = 1598L, `1603` = 1603L, `1604` = 1604L, `1606` = 1606L, 
`1611` = 1611L, `1614` = 1614L, `1615` = 1615L, `1616` = 1616L, 
`1619` = 1619L, `1620` = 1620L, `1621` = 1621L, `1623` = 1623L, 
`1633` = 1633L, `1634` = 1634L, `1638` = 1638L, `1641` = 1641L, 
`1645` = 1645L, `1651` = 1651L, `1653` = 1653L, `1656` = 1656L, 
`1657` = 1657L, `1659` = 1659L, `1660` = 1660L, `1661` = 1661L, 
`1665` = 1665L, `1666` = 1666L, `1671` = 1671L, `1672` = 1672L, 
`1673` = 1673L, `1679` = 1679L, `1681` = 1681L, `1682` = 1682L, 
`1683` = 1683L, `1686` = 1686L, `1692` = 1692L, `1695` = 1695L, 
`1698` = 1698L, `1699` = 1699L, `1700` = 1700L, `1701` = 1701L, 
`1705` = 1705L, `1710` = 1710L, `1712` = 1712L, `1713` = 1713L, 
`1715` = 1715L, `1719` = 1719L, `1725` = 1725L, `1726` = 1726L, 
`1727` = 1727L, `1728` = 1728L, `1731` = 1731L, `1732` = 1732L, 
`1733` = 1733L, `1734` = 1734L, `1736` = 1736L, `1737` = 1737L, 
`1738` = 1738L, `1740` = 1740L, `1747` = 1747L, `1748` = 1748L, 
`1754` = 1754L, `1755` = 1755L, `1756` = 1756L, `1758` = 1758L, 
`1761` = 1761L, `1769` = 1769L, `1772` = 1772L, `1776` = 1776L, 
`1777` = 1777L, `1778` = 1778L, `1782` = 1782L, `1788` = 1788L, 
`1789` = 1789L, `1791` = 1791L, `1793` = 1793L, `1795` = 1795L, 
`1796` = 1796L, `1797` = 1797L, `1798` = 1798L, `1800` = 1800L, 
`1807` = 1807L, `1811` = 1811L, `1812` = 1812L, `1815` = 1815L, 
`1817` = 1817L, `1823` = 1823L, `1824` = 1824L, `1827` = 1827L, 
`1830` = 1830L, `1831` = 1831L, `1832` = 1832L, `1833` = 1833L, 
`1835` = 1835L, `1836` = 1836L, `1843` = 1843L, `1844` = 1844L, 
`1845` = 1845L, `1847` = 1847L, `1850` = 1850L, `1851` = 1851L, 
`1852` = 1852L, `1853` = 1853L, `1857` = 1857L, `1862` = 1862L, 
`1864` = 1864L, `1865` = 1865L, `1867` = 1867L, `1871` = 1871L, 
`1872` = 1872L, `1873` = 1873L, `1883` = 1883L, `1888` = 1888L, 
`1893` = 1893L, `1897` = 1897L, `1898` = 1898L, `1904` = 1904L, 
`1905` = 1905L, `1906` = 1906L, `1908` = 1908L, `1911` = 1911L, 
`1920` = 1920L, `1923` = 1923L, `1926` = 1926L, `1927` = 1927L, 
`1928` = 1928L, `1929` = 1929L, `1931` = 1931L, `1933` = 1933L, 
`1938` = 1938L, `1940` = 1940L, `1941` = 1941L, `1943` = 1943L, 
`1948` = 1948L, `1954` = 1954L, `1955` = 1955L, `1956` = 1956L, 
`1959` = 1959L, `1961` = 1961L, `1967` = 1967L, `1968` = 1968L, 
`1969` = 1969L, `1970` = 1970L, `1973` = 1973L, `1974` = 1974L, 
`1975` = 1975L, `1978` = 1978L, `1985` = 1985L, `1989` = 1989L, 
`1990` = 1990L, `1995` = 1995L, `2000` = 2000L, `2001` = 2001L, 
`2003` = 2003L, `2007` = 2007L, `2008` = 2008L, `2009` = 2009L, 
`2014` = 2014L, `2023` = 2023L, `2025` = 2025L, `2027` = 2027L, 
`2028` = 2028L, `2029` = 2029L, `2031` = 2031L, `2033` = 2033L, 
`2036` = 2036L, `2040` = 2040L, `2042` = 2042L, `2043` = 2043L, 
`2048` = 2048L, `2049` = 2049L, `2055` = 2055L, `2056` = 2056L, 
`2060` = 2060L, `2061` = 2061L, `2062` = 2062L, `2063` = 2063L, 
`2067` = 2067L, `2069` = 2069L, `2074` = 2074L, `2077` = 2077L, 
`2078` = 2078L, `2080` = 2080L, `2082` = 2082L, `2083` = 2083L, 
`2084` = 2084L, `2086` = 2086L, `2089` = 2089L, `2091` = 2091L, 
`2092` = 2092L, `2093` = 2093L, `2096` = 2096L, `2097` = 2097L, 
`2102` = 2102L, `2103` = 2103L, `2106` = 2106L, `2107` = 2107L, 
`2108` = 2108L, `2112` = 2112L, `2113` = 2113L, `2116` = 2116L, 
`2121` = 2121L, `2125` = 2125L, `2126` = 2126L, `2127` = 2127L, 
`2135` = 2135L, `2136` = 2136L, `2140` = 2140L, `2141` = 2141L, 
`2146` = 2146L, `2150` = 2150L, `2156` = 2156L, `2158` = 2158L, 
`2159` = 2159L, `2162` = 2162L, `2164` = 2164L, `2165` = 2165L, 
`2166` = 2166L, `2167` = 2167L, `2170` = 2170L, `2171` = 2171L, 
`2172` = 2172L, `2174` = 2174L, `2177` = 2177L, `2178` = 2178L, 
`2182` = 2182L, `2183` = 2183L, `2184` = 2184L, `2186` = 2186L, 
`2188` = 2188L, `2189` = 2189L, `2190` = 2190L, `2192` = 2192L, 
`2196` = 2196L, `2200` = 2200L, `2201` = 2201L, `2202` = 2202L, 
`2208` = 2208L, `2210` = 2210L, `2211` = 2211L, `2212` = 2212L, 
`2215` = 2215L, `2216` = 2216L, `2221` = 2221L, `2225` = 2225L, 
`2231` = 2231L, `2232` = 2232L, `2233` = 2233L, `2234` = 2234L, 
`2237` = 2237L, `2238` = 2238L, `2239` = 2239L, `2240` = 2240L, 
`2241` = 2241L, `2243` = 2243L, `2244` = 2244L, `2246` = 2246L, 
`2253` = 2253L, `2254` = 2254L, `2259` = 2259L, `2260` = 2260L, 
`2264` = 2264L, `2265` = 2265L, `2266` = 2266L, `2273` = 2273L, 
`2276` = 2276L, `2278` = 2278L, `2280` = 2280L, `2284` = 2284L, 
`2286` = 2286L, `2288` = 2288L, `2289` = 2289L, `2292` = 2292L, 
`2295` = 2295L, `2296` = 2296L, `2297` = 2297L, `2301` = 2301L, 
`2302` = 2302L, `2308` = 2308L, `2311` = 2311L, `2312` = 2312L, 
`2317` = 2317L, `2321` = 2321L, `2324` = 2324L, `2326` = 2326L, 
`2330` = 2330L, `2331` = 2331L, `2332` = 2332L, `2338` = 2338L, 
`2340` = 2340L, `2341` = 2341L, `2342` = 2342L, `2345` = 2345L, 
`2346` = 2346L, `2349` = 2349L, `2351` = 2351L, `2356` = 2356L, 
`2358` = 2358L, `2359` = 2359L, `2362` = 2362L, `2363` = 2363L, 
`2368` = 2368L, `2372` = 2372L, `2375` = 2375L, `2377` = 2377L, 
`2380` = 2380L, `2381` = 2381L, `2387` = 2387L, `2388` = 2388L, 
`2393` = 2393L, `2394` = 2394L, `2395` = 2395L, `2396` = 2396L, 
`2402` = 2402L, `2409` = 2409L, `2410` = 2410L, `2414` = 2414L, 
`2415` = 2415L, `2420` = 2420L, `2421` = 2421L, `2422` = 2422L, 
`2426` = 2426L, `2432` = 2432L, `2435` = 2435L, `2436` = 2436L, 
`2437` = 2437L, `2443` = 2443L, `2445` = 2445L, `2446` = 2446L, 
`2447` = 2447L, `2450` = 2450L, `2451` = 2451L, `2454` = 2454L, 
`2456` = 2456L, `2461` = 2461L, `2465` = 2465L, `2468` = 2468L, 
`2469` = 2469L, `2470` = 2470L, `2471` = 2471L, `2473` = 2473L, 
`2474` = 2474L, `2481` = 2481L, `2482` = 2482L, `2483` = 2483L, 
`2487` = 2487L, `2489` = 2489L, `2490` = 2490L, `2493` = 2493L, 
`2494` = 2494L, `2499` = 2499L, `2503` = 2503L, `2506` = 2506L, 
`2508` = 2508L, `2513` = 2513L, `2515` = 2515L, `2517` = 2517L, 
`2518` = 2518L, `2522` = 2522L, `2524` = 2524L, `2529` = 2529L, 
`2532` = 2532L, `2534` = 2534L, `2537` = 2537L, `2538` = 2538L, 
`2544` = 2544L, `2545` = 2545L, `2546` = 2546L, `2548` = 2548L, 
`2549` = 2549L, `2551` = 2551L, `2555` = 2555L, `2560` = 2560L, 
`2564` = 2564L, `2565` = 2565L, `2567` = 2567L, `2571` = 2571L, 
`2572` = 2572L, `2573` = 2573L, `2578` = 2578L, `2582` = 2582L, 
`2587` = 2587L, `2592` = 2592L, `2593` = 2593L, `2596` = 2596L, 
`2599` = 2599L, `2600` = 2600L, `2601` = 2601L, `2602` = 2602L, 
`2604` = 2604L, `2605` = 2605L, `2614` = 2614L, `2618` = 2618L, 
`2622` = 2622L, `2624` = 2624L, `2626` = 2626L, `2627` = 2627L, 
`2630` = 2630L, `2633` = 2633L, `2634` = 2634L, `2638` = 2638L, 
`2639` = 2639L, `2640` = 2640L, `2645` = 2645L, `2646` = 2646L, 
`2650` = 2650L, `2651` = 2651L, `2652` = 2652L, `2654` = 2654L, 
`2656` = 2656L, `2657` = 2657L, `2660` = 2660L, `2663` = 2663L, 
`2665` = 2665L, `2669` = 2669L, `2671` = 2671L, `2672` = 2672L, 
`2675` = 2675L, `2676` = 2676L, `2681` = 2681L, `2685` = 2685L, 
`2690` = 2690L, `2695` = 2695L, `2699` = 2699L, `2702` = 2702L, 
`2704` = 2704L, `2705` = 2705L, `2707` = 2707L, `2708` = 2708L, 
`2712` = 2712L, `2717` = 2717L, `2721` = 2721L, `2725` = 2725L, 
`2728` = 2728L, `2730` = 2730L, `2731` = 2731L, `2733` = 2733L, 
`2734` = 2734L, `2738` = 2738L, `2743` = 2743L, `2746` = 2746L, 
`2747` = 2747L, `2749` = 2749L, `2753` = 2753L, `2754` = 2754L, 
`2755` = 2755L, `2760` = 2760L, `2764` = 2764L, `2769` = 2769L, 
`2773` = 2773L, `2774` = 2774L, `2780` = 2780L, `2781` = 2781L, 
`2782` = 2782L, `2784` = 2784L, `2785` = 2785L, `2787` = 2787L, 
`2789` = 2789L, `2791` = 2791L, `2796` = 2796L, `2801` = 2801L, 
`2805` = 2805L, `2808` = 2808L, `2810` = 2810L, `2811` = 2811L, 
`2813` = 2813L, `2818` = 2818L, `2823` = 2823L), class = "omit"), row.names = c(2L, 
3L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 31L, 33L, 35L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 48L, 52L, 
54L, 56L, 57L, 61L, 62L, 64L, 65L, 69L, 71L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 79L, 
80L, 82L, 83L, 87L, 88L, 90L, 91L, 95L, 97L, 101L, 103L, 105L, 
106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 120L, 124L, 
125L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 131L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 
142L, 144L, 147L, 148L, 150L, 154L, 155L, 157L, 159L, 161L, 162L, 
163L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 177L, 
178L, 179L, 180L, 182L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to modify and filter the underlying data. So, create a nested list of all possible combinations of the filter values, and then use the `reduce()` function from the `purrr` package to apply the filtering iteratively.

***Example:***

Let's say I want to filter my nutritional supplement sales. Assume we have a dataframe, `df`, with columns `Supplement`, `Customer`, and `OrderNumber`.

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)

# Create a nested list of all possible filter combinations
filters <- list(
  by_Supplement = split(df, df$Supplement),
  by_customer = map(filters$by_Supplement, ~split(.x, .x$Customer)),
  by_order_number = map(filters$by_customer, ~map(.x, ~split(.x, .x$OrderNumber)))
)

# Define a function to filter the data by a list of filter values
filter_data <- function(data, filters) {
  reduce(filters, function(data, filter) {
    if (!is.null(filter)) {
      data %>% filter(!!!filter)
    } else {
      data
    }
  }, .init = data)
}

# Define the Shiny app UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("Supplement", "Supplement", choices = names(filters$by_Supplement)),
  uiOutput("customer"),
  uiOutput("order_number"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

# Define the Shiny app server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$customer <- renderUI({
    Supplement_data <- filters$by_Supplement[[input$Supplement]]
    selectInput("customer", "Customer", choices = c("", names(Supplement_data)))
  })
  
  output$order_number <- renderUI({
    Supplement_data <- filters$by_Supplement[[input$Supplement]]
    if (!is.null(input$customer)) {
      customer_data <- Supplement_data[[input$customer]]
      selectInput("order_number", "Order Number", choices = c("", customer_data$OrderNumber))
    } else {
      selectInput("order_number", "Order Number", choices = "")
    }
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    filter_values <- list(Supplement = input$Supplement, Customer = input$customer, OrderNumber = input$order_number)
    filtered_data <- filter_data(df, map(filters, ~if (!is.null(.x)) .x[[filter_values[[names(.x)]]]]))
    filtered_data
  })
}

# Run the Shiny app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

`filter_data()` goes into `output$table` with a list of filter values, via `map()` and has the currently selected values of all three select boxes, regardless of the order of selection.